# Visual Studio 2015 TypeScript 2.1 Definintions locations

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-2015, type-definition

I am trying to create a React-Redux web app in VS 2015, and I'm having issues trying to do everything in TypeScript.

I added the react and redux modules via NPM, along with the @types.  When I tried to import those modules into my TS file, I got the red squiggle saying that the module "react" could not be found.  I then downloaded the Definitively Typed NuGet package, and the red squiggle disappeared.

HOWEVER, the project wouldn't compile with both @types and Definitively Typed definitions in the same project.

Is there a flag I'm missing in the tsconfig file that forces Visual Studio 2015 to search the `node_modules` folder for .d.ts files?

Answer (score 1):

Since I know that it can be a bit of a struggle to set up Typescript and React in VS, I wanted to say that the best guide for me lately, that worked for both Windows and non-Windows systems, has been the one from the [Typescript site](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/react-&-webpack.html).

It uses the `@types` (which I'd recommend) and a `tsconfig.json`, which you don't necessarily need in VS, because you can configure almost the same things in your project's Properties, but helps, if you don't only have VS as an environment. The guide also includes instructions for a webpack setup.

For comparison, this is what one of my `tsconfig.json` currently looks like:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "sourceMap": true,
    "module": "commonjs",
    "target": "es5",
    "jsx": "react"
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "wwwroot",
    "obj"
  ]
}
```